# How to select all the list items(li) between two specific list items using Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is the code. An unordered list (ul) which contains multiple list items (li)

There are few li which has role="none". I want to select all li elements which are present between two consecutive li.role="none". And then I want to wrap those li with a ul tag.

For example 1st li & 3rd li has role="none".  So, the 2nd li should be wrapped with ul tag.

```html
<ul class="tl-unit-list tl-catalog-left-space" id="tl-course-info-units-list" role="none">
  <li role="none"><span class="label label-section" style="font-size: 14px;" role="heading" aria-level="3">Pre-assessment</span></li>
  <li>
    <a class="none-decoration tl-course-info-unit" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="icon-ok tl-green-ok tl-icon16 tl-gray-icon" style="margin-right: 8px;"></i></a>
    <a href="https://dequeindia.talentlms.com/unit/viewtestsurvey/id:2076,mode:survey">Pre-assessment</a>
  </li>

  <li role="none"><span class="label label-section" style="font-size: 14px;" role="heading" aria-level="3">Web Accessibility</span></li>
  <li>
    <a class="none-decoration tl-course-info-unit" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="icon-ok tl-green-ok tl-icon16 tl-gray-icon" style="margin-right: 8px;"></i></a>
    <a href="https://dequeindia.talentlms.com/unit/view/id:2053">Introduction</a></li>
  <li><i class="icon-video tl-icon16 tl-gray-icon tl-cursor-default" style="margin-right: 8px;"></i><a href="https://dequeindia.talentlms.com/unit/view/id:2054">What is web accessibility?</a></li>
  <li><i class="icon-test tl-icon16 tl-gray-icon tl-cursor-default" style="margin-right: 8px;"></i><span class="tl-disabled">Quiz</span></li>

  <li role="none"><span class="label label-section" style="font-size: 14px;" role="heading" aria-level="3">Disabilities</span></li>
  <li><i class="icon-video tl-icon16 tl-gray-icon tl-cursor-default" style="margin-right: 8px;"></i><span class="tl-disabled">Types of Disabilities</span></li>
  <li><i class="icon-doc-alt tl-icon16 tl-gray-icon tl-cursor-default" style="margin-right: 8px;"></i><span class="tl-disabled">Types of Disabilities - Personas</span></li>
  <li><i class="icon-doc-alt tl-icon16 tl-gray-icon tl-cursor-default" style="margin-right: 8px;"></i><span class="tl-disabled">Blind</span></li>
  <li><i class="icon-video tl-icon16 tl-gray-icon tl-cursor-default" style="margin-right: 8px;"></i><span class="tl-disabled">Low Vision</span></li>
  <li><i class="icon-doc-alt tl-icon16 tl-gray-icon tl-cursor-default" style="margin-right: 8px;"></i><span class="tl-disabled">Color Blindness</span></li>
  <li><i class="icon-test tl-icon16 tl-gray-icon tl-cursor-default" style="margin-right: 8px;"></i><span class="tl-disabled">Quiz</span></li>
  <li><i class="icon-doc-alt tl-icon16 tl-gray-icon tl-cursor-default" style="margin-right: 8px;"></i><span class="tl-disabled">Deaf</span></li>
  <li><i class="icon-doc-alt tl-icon16 tl-gray-icon tl-cursor-default" style="margin-right: 8px;"></i><span class="tl-disabled">DeafBlind</span></li>

  <li role="none"><span class="label label-section" style="font-size: 14px;" role="heading" aria-level="3">Guidelines</span></li>
  <li><i class="icon-doc-alt tl-icon16 tl-gray-icon tl-cursor-default" style="margin-right: 8px;"></i><span class="tl-disabled">Introduction</span></li>
  <li><i class="icon-video tl-icon16 tl-gray-icon tl-cursor-default" style="margin-right: 8px;"></i><span class="tl-disabled">Web Content Accessibility Guidelines (WCAG)</span></li>
  <li><i class="icon-video tl-icon16 tl-gray-icon tl-cursor-default" style="margin-right: 8px;"></i><span class="tl-disabled">Authoring Tool Accessibility Guidelines (ATAG)</span></li>
  <li><i class="icon-video tl-icon16 tl-gray-icon tl-cursor-default" style="margin-right: 8px;"></i><span class="tl-disabled">ARIA</span></li>

  <li role="none"><span class="label label-section" style="font-size: 14px;" role="heading" aria-level="3">Laws</span></li>
  <li><i class="icon-doc-alt tl-icon16 tl-gray-icon tl-cursor-default" style="margin-right: 8px;"></i><span class="tl-disabled">Introduction</span></li>
  <li><i class="icon-video tl-icon16 tl-gray-icon tl-cursor-default" style="margin-right: 8px;"></i><span class="tl-disabled">United States</span></li>
  <li><i class="icon-video tl-icon16 tl-gray-icon tl-cursor-default" style="margin-right: 8px;"></i><span class="tl-disabled">Canada</span></li>
  <li><i class="icon-video tl-icon16 tl-gray-icon tl-cursor-default" style="margin-right: 8px;"></i><span class="tl-disabled">Europe</span></li>
  <li><i class="icon-video tl-icon16 tl-gray-icon tl-cursor-default" style="margin-right: 8px;"></i><span class="tl-disabled">Other regions</span></li>

  <li role="none"><span class="label label-section" style="font-size: 14px;" role="heading" aria-level="3">Myths</span></li>
  <li><i class="icon-doc-alt tl-icon16 tl-gray-icon tl-cursor-default" style="margin-right: 8px;"></i><span class="tl-disabled">Introduction</span></li>
  <li><i class="icon-video tl-icon16 tl-gray-icon tl-cursor-default" style="margin-right: 8px;"></i><span class="tl-disabled">Myths</span></li>

  <li role="none"><span class="label label-section" style="font-size: 14px;" role="heading" aria-level="3">Summary</span></li>
  <li><i class="icon-doc-alt tl-icon16 tl-gray-icon tl-cursor-default" style="margin-right: 8px;"></i><span class="tl-disabled">Summary</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: First I would search on how to select element by specific attribute. then I would search on how to wrap element. When you have searched both and done them you should be done.

Comment: It would likely take you a shorter time just to edit the HTML manually...

Comment: @HereticMonkey, Thanks for editing the HTML. It's my very first question on stackoverflow, so I was not familiar with the formatting. Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

I tried below steps, and it worked.

Step:1. With help of Jquery, I added a unique Id to all the list items which has role="none".  For example :

```
       <li id="list-heading-0" role="none"><span class="label label-section" style="font-size: 14px;" role="heading" aria-level="3">Pre-assessment</span></li>
```

Step: 2: Execute the below code. Iterate over all the List items having role= none , and then use nextUntil() and wrapAll() methods of Jquery.

```
      $('ul#tl-course-info-units-list > li[role="none"]').each(function(index,element) { 
         var counter = index; 
         var nextCounter = index+1;
         $('#tl-course-info-units-list li#list-heading-'+counter).nextUntil($('#tl-course-info-units-list li#list-heading-'+nextCounter)).wrapAll('<ul />');
      });
```